# form needs to be execute exactly once after installation in c#.net

Tags: c#

I have developed c#.net windows application which consist multiple form. 1st form is consist basic info about user. what i want is after installing my software,when you run program for a first time all forms should get executed. and from 2nd time it should execute all forms except basic info form. so how to do that ?
Thank You.

Comment: Use some persistent datastore (database, file) to save information which will stay between application runs

Comment: You should accept an answer when you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add settings file to your project and put in an **user** setting "FirstRun" with default value  `true`.

Then add a check to your mainform which checks this setting

```
 if (Settings.Default.FirstRun) {
   new FirstTimeRunForm().ShowDialog(); 
   Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
   Settings.Default.Save();
 }
```

.

Answer (score 0):

If a file does not exist, open the form and at the end create the file with 0 bytes.
At the next start you'll find the file and not open the form.

```
if (!File.Exists("form_done"))
{
    // open form
    File.WriteAllBytes("form_done", new byte[0]);
}
```

Otherwise, use the [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I don't like approach with `form_done` file. Saving data to Settings is much better. But I forgot about registry, which is also very good approach, even better than saving data to files